# SQL Server : Hashbytes with Umlauts

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sha256, hashbytes

I have a strange situation figured out, when the `Hashbyte` function of SQL Server is not outputting the correct result when converting it to `SHA2_256` with a string containing umlauts (ä,ö,ü,ß).

I run the example code in SQL Server:

```
 declare @cryptString varchar(50) 
 set @cryptString = 'test'

 select convert(Varchar(64), Hashbytes('SHA2_256', @cryptstring), 2)
```

The result is:

```
9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08
```

When I'm checking the SHA256 conversion on https://hashgenerator.de/ the result is the same.

My problem: when I'm trying to crypt for example 'müller', the result in SQL Server is:

```
26A45113433596C5DD53643C7652381202E8009E532A280E513D887174A9ED14
```

When I'm checking the SHA256 conversion on https://hashgenerator.de/ the result is different.

```
2dbd218072117713f2d5996a726a9b216ed791ffd0783b6ba4ab6d61b8333192
```

I think it could be a encoding problem, but I searched for hours and can't find any clue to solve this problem.

I appreciate any kind of help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
declare @cryptString varchar(50)
```

And you try to use it to hold this value:

```
müller
```

That's bad. You need an `nvarchar` for anything that could go beyond basic ascii characters.

But that's just for starters. [`nvarchar` uses UTF-16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support) (see the section headed "Supplementary Characters" about halfway down the page). The web site may be using UTF-32 or (likely) UTF-8 to encode those characters. Either one will use slightly different byte representations, which will produce completely different hash values.

I believe you're seeing UTF-8 at https://hashgenerator.de/, because UTF-8 matches ASCII when only using ASCII characters. With UTF-8, simple values like `test` would then produce the same result for both the web site and the database.

To fix this, understand the SQL hash **will** use either ASCII or UTF-16, and so you must change your encoding on whatever other platform you're using to match the database. The simplest option is probably to always use UTF-16 for these values, but you could also choose to stick with `varchar` on the database and convert your text to ascii before calculating the hash elsewhere (with the understanding that you'll lose some fidelity).

Comment: I did exactly the same [Demo](http://rextester.com/BJYFM89518). Still result differs.

Comment: @lad2025 There's more in the answer now.

Comment: @lad2025 thank you for your detailed explanation, I guessed it could be this sort of problem. In my normal application flow the frontend will Hash the String to SHA256 and saving it to the db and in the next steps I'm only comparing those Crypted Strings. Momentarily I'm only using this method to migrate old data to a new one and have to crypt them. I will figure it out on monday when I'm working on it.

Comment: Fixed the problem with the knowledge of @lad2025 and the correct answer of this stackoverflow article [MD5-Hash-of-a-utf8-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200452/compute-md5-hash-of-a-utf8-string). Using this TableFunction before to hash the string did the trick for me. I think it's obvious what the function is doing.